# How to identify cell is merged cell with google sheets api

Tags: go, google-sheets-api

I'm using Go API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go

I have a sheet looks like this and want to automate some cell filling logic

```
  |  B   |  C   |
--+------+------+
1 |  b1  |  c1  |
--+------+      |
2 |  b2  |      |
--+------+------+
3 |  b3  |      |
--+------+------+
```

While using `readRange := "B1:C"` by

```
resp, _ := s.srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()
for _, row := range resp.Values {
   ...
}
```

I can't tell the difference between C2 and C3. In this case, I would like to fill some values to C3 but not C2. How do I check this via API?

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You want to retrieve the information of merge cells in a sheet using Sheets API. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to write something to only 1 cell among all empty cells in column C. In the above case, I want to write to C3 but not to C2. However, I can't tell if C2 is a real cell by itself or a merged cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to put a value to "C3". But ``Spreadsheets.Values.Get()`` is used for retrieving values. About this situation, I'm confusing. Can I ask you about what you want to do?

Comment: It's a sign-up form, I want to sign up in only 1 cell column C, but some timeslots are occupied by the same person (as merged cells). So like in the example, I want to sign up at first available empty timeslot, but I can't tell the difference between C2 and C3 from API.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to put the values to the column "C". But before putting the values, you want to retrieve the information of merged cells. I could understand like this. By this understanding, I proposed the method for retrieving the information of merged cells as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the information of merge cells in a sheet using Sheets API.

From your replying, I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, the method of spreadsheets.values.get cannot retrieve the information of merge cells. In this case, please use the method of spreadsheets.get. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
ranges := []string{"B1:C"}
resp, _ := s.srv.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId).Ranges(ranges...).Do()
for _, sheet := range resp.Sheets {
    for _, merge := range sheet.Merges {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", merge)
    }
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already used Sheets API.
- Range of `B1:C` means `B1:C` of the first tab.
- When you run above script, you can retrieve the coordinates of the merged cells as the GridRange like below.

  ```
  {
    "sheetId": 0,
    "startRowIndex": 0,
    "endRowIndex": 2,
    "startColumnIndex": 2,
    "endColumnIndex": 3
  }
  ```

  - This GridRange is `C1:C2` of sheet ID `0` as the a1Notation.

    - From above result, it is found that `C1:C2` is the merged cell.
    - In this case, when the value is put in `C1`, the value is displayed. But when the value is put in `C2`, the value is not displayed. Please be careful this.
  - If you want to put the value using the GridRange, you can use the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)
- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: Cool thanks, exactly what I need to figure out merged cells

Comment: @Ray Wu I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.